# Universal iPhone/iPad app size concern

Tags: iphone, ipad, size, universal

It is recommended by Apple to make universal apps, i.e. one ipa for iPhone and iPad. If I make a standalone iPhone app, it gets approx. 6Mb. If I make a universal app it becomes approx. 19Mb... For iPhone users this is a waste... (size is build up of iPad image resources). This feels wrong to me... Please comment.

Comment: 13 MB isn't *that much*. I think 13 MB is worth much less than the money needed to buy the app twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you sell your app, users which own an ipad and an iphone would need to buy your app twice, if they want to use it on both devices. I would prefer the waste of 12mb.

Comment: Ok, I understand this. What then are all those "HD" versions in App Store? What is the reason making two versions?

Comment: when the ipad came out it was cool to call your app "HD" .. because it had higher resolution. they made it a new app to sell it again :) nowadays HD is often also used for apps with retina support.

Answer (score 0):

Contra: extra size.

Pro: you will need promote two apps, users who own iPhone and iPad will need buy twice.